# I am looking for a methodology for categorizing keywords

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I.e. I want to put in Baseball and get out Sports & Outdoors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

The relation beween Baseball and Sports is called hypernym.

Here is a snippet out of WordNet's [*baseball* hypernym hierarchy](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=baseball&i=3&h=1001000#c):

> S: (n) baseball, baseball game, ball (a ball game played with a bat
>   and ball between two teams of nine players; teams take turns at bat
>   trying to score runs) "he played baseball in high school"; "there was
>   a baseball game on every empty lot"; "there was a desire for National
>   League ball in the area"; "play ball!" direct hyponym / full hyponym
>   domain term category direct hypernym / inherited hypernym / sister
>   term S: (n) ball game, ballgame (a field game played with a ball
>   (especially baseball)) S: (n) field game (an outdoor game played on a
>   field of specified dimensions) S: (n) outdoor game (an athletic game
>   that is played outdoors) S: (n) athletic game (a game involving
>   athletic activity) S: (n) sport, athletics (an active diversion
>   requiring physical exertion and competition) S: (n) diversion,
>   recreation (an activity that diverts or amuses or stimulates) "scuba
>   diving is provided as a diversion for tourists"; "for recreation he
>   wrote poetry and solved crossword puzzles"; "drug abuse is often
>   regarded as a form of recreation" S: (n) activity (any specific
>   behavior) "they avoided all recreational activity" S: (n) act, deed,
>   human action, human activity (something that people do or cause to
>   happen) S: (n) event (something that happens at a given place and
>   time) S: (n) psychological feature (a feature of the mental life of a
>   living organism) S: (n) abstraction, abstract entity (a  ...